# Как в список записать таблицу с Excel файла, модулем CSV?

Tags: python

Как в список записать таблицу из Excel  начиная со второй строчки таблицы ?

Записывают таблицу в Excel

```
file_name = 'items.csv'
with open(file_name, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(['==РАСПРОДАЖА=='])
    for item in res:
        writer.writerow([item])
```

Мне нужно

1. Записать из файла items.csv (таблица Excel) таблицу в список начиная со второй строчки.
2. Добавить  в файл items.csv к существующей таблице , новую таблицу справа.

Answer (score 3):

Не понимаю, чего вы мудрите.

Чтение из файла минуя первую строку

```
csv_iter =  csv.reader(file('items.csv'))
next(csv_iter)
for row in csv_iter:
      print (row)
```

Вместо print (row)  -  можно записывать в ваш список spis.append(row)

Когда список в памяти - расширяете его "справа" как вам надо и полученный расширенный список записываете в файл, как угодно, ну для разнообразия например так:

```
myFile = open('items.csv', 'w')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(spis)
```

Если пропуск первой строки связан с тем, что там записаны имена столбцов, то рекомендую пользоваться csv.DictReader и csv.DictWriter

Наконец, еще один способ - читать через таблицу Pandas, которую и расширить легче и обрабатывать проще. Правда, это не чистый модуль CSV, конечно.